# How to add data attribute to cell text in Datatables Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, jquery-datatables-editor

In the initialation of datatables together with editor i use:

```
columns: [
  { data: "name", className: 'noEdit clickTextToOpenModal'  },
```

I can set className within this line of code.
Is it possible to add data-attributes in this line to?
I would like to add something like:

```
{ data: "name", className: 'noEdit transactionModalBtn', data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#transactionModal"},
```

where can i find all thoose commands availible?
Like: data:, className:, etc?
Is there one for data-atrributes?

If it's not possible, how should i add data-attributes to open modal, best practice?

**UPDATE**
I've now tried:

```
{ data: "name", className: 'noEdit transactionModalBtn', createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){$(td).data("data-bs-toggle", "modal"); $(td).data("data-bs-target", "#transactionModal");}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to add the code inside:

```
columns: [
  { data: "name", className: 'noEdit transactionModalBtn'},
```

So i did this, and it worked:

```
columns: [
  { data: "name", className: 'noEdit transactionModalBtn'}
],
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  $( row ).find('td.transactionModalBtn').attr('data-bs-toggle', 'modal');
  $( row ).find('td.transactionModalBtn').attr('data-bs-target', '#transactionModal');
    },
```